# No severity from SonarQube server in SonarLint for VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, sonarlint

I have installed SonarLint for Visual Studio and connect to our SonarQube server. I bind it (and even updated it). It seems to work but when I compare the settings in Visual Studio to the SonarQube settings I see that the severity is not the same!? So I work connected but it seems that SonarLint is not using the severity from Rules set on our SonarQube server. When developers have different severities when working in Visual Studio compared to the SonarQube server it, of course, wont work. Any suggestions how this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered on the SonarLint mailing list, here: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sonarlint/62E37g-0lnA/discussion

I can confirm that severities configured on SQ side are not taken into account in SonarLint for Visual Studio (connected mode). In VS, we treat all issues as warnings. The reason for this is that

- we don't want to break the build inside VS, while if a blocker or critical issue was detected that would most probably be mapped to a VS error,
- in SQ there are 5 severity levels, while in VS there are 3 (+ issues can be faded).

Breaking the build is only acceptable if there are absolutely no false positives reported. While we constantly aim at this, we are not confident enough to say there are no false positives. The severity level mapping could be done, and will come at one point.